# Azure Marketplace - Do I need to create VM offer separately from Azure Applications offer?

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I'm going to make an solution offer to Azure Marketplace using this documents.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/partner-center-portal/create-new-azure-apps-offer

I have already created the ARM templates. But inside my templates, they're referring to custom images in Share Images Gallery that I captured from Azure Portal. Do i need to create VMs offer for my Images separately?

If yes, Let say if I have 10 templates that are referring to 20 custom images in Share Images Gallery, then I need to create 20 VM offers for 20 custom images, don't I?

Sorry I very new on Azure Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much detail here is an answer based on some assumptions:

1. The Azure App is meant for public customers
2. The Azure App (ARM Template) is going to deploy Virtual Machine images

If that’s the right set of assumptions then: Using Shared Image Gallery would turn out to be a costly exercise because it would be someone’s Storage account. The preferred solution would be

1. Create a Azure Virtual Machine offer
2. Each offer can have many plans (selling motion)
3. Each plan can have up to 40 versions of an image
4. Keep the VM offer hidden, so users don’t buy that, instead publish an Azure App that manages the deployments

Another way to think about it is, if you have same product with many versions, you create a single plan
If you have same product with different tiers you can create different plans (and code your VM to query azure to find out what context (plan) its running in and behave appropriately)
You want to keep the same “offering” under the same “offer”. For example all Windows Server images are under the same offer (with plans for each major release)
If you are offering a banana in one image and a potato in the other, you want to put them in different offers.

Comment: Thank you. My Azure Applicaiton creates 3 VMs from separate images.  
If I create a single plan, with 3 versions. (version 1:Image A, version 2:Image B, version 3: Image C)  
then, in my ARM code for VM1 will be look like this:  
```
"imageReference": {
  "publisher": "MyCompany",  
  "offer": "MyOffer",  
  "sku": "MyPlan",  
  "version": "1"  
}
```
Question is: Is it ok for using `"version": "1"`?   
Because I read from Best practice on Azure Github say that:  
If a template contains an imageReference using an platform image, the version property must be `latest`.

Comment: You can have images in 3 separate plans and create 3 VMs from them.

Regarding Shared Image Gallery, another issue besides cost is that it may be accidentally removed by the customer (in this case, ISV) without knowing that it serves an Azure App in Marketplace. Managing the images in Marketplace may reduce that risk as the controls are in a single place - Partner Center.